# How to allow access to user-defined variables by entering user_id (no password) in url?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a members site which requires login where members create web pages with specific user-defined variables to enter data which will be shown for public access to these web pages, each of which displays information on a certain product.

There are 7 common web page templates which all members choose from to display custom variables related to them, their company, and a specific product (one of seven). They enter their custom information in to a form, which then places these values in the proper places on the web page templates to be viewed by prospects later

```
<input name='first_name' value='first_name'>
<input name='last_name' value='last_name'>
<input name='company_name' value='company_name'>
<input name='phone_number' value='phone_number'>
<input name='product_id' value='product_id'>
<input name='product_size' value='product_size'>
<input name='product_color' value='product_color'>
<input name='product_price' value='product_price'>
```

I need to be able to access the values of these variables pertaining to the specific user and specific product offered by user when a webpage is accessed with the user_id in the URL, ie something like http://domain.com/page_template_1/user_id/product_id.

Right now, only the user has access to these values when he is logged in. I need these values to be accessible to anyone accessing a specific url where user's custom values his show product information.

Comment: You should be able to write a query for the user_id that retrieves the seven custom fields for display in the page.  Are these values stored together in a table along with user_id?

Comment: Yes, all values are in the same table, same row as the user_id. Could you give me an example of the query I would include in the file I access using the user_id as a unique identifier in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I couldn't get anything to work for me except the following. It could have been the way the rest of the code on my page is constructed. I don't know. But here is what I did which works. Kind of a pain to have to use $row->variable_name instead of $variable_name. But it works.

```
$db_connection = new mysqli("", "", "");
if ($db_connection->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .       $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$id = $_GET['user_id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);

echo " // HTML GOES HERE

  $row->first_name
  $row->last_name
  $row->company_name

 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

A query might look like this:

```
<?php
$db_connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if ($db_connection->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


$user_id = $_GET['user_id']; // from url
$product_id = $_GET['product_id']; // from url
// Make sure $db_connection matched your database connect script! Other wise it will come up with "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" error.
if($stmt = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name, company_name, phone_number, product_id, product_size, product_color, product_price FROM table_name WHERE user_id = ? AND product_id = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $product_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $company_name, $phone_number, $product_id, $product_size, $product_color, $product_price);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $first_name;
        $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

You might also want to rewrite your urls using the .htaccess file. if you want your urls to be pretty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /localhost/domain/file.php`

Comment: You need to replace table_name with your table name?? I am using this code on a page now and is works i have just tested it.

Comment: I have just edited the code, that is the exact code i am using which works. check that your field names match up to those in the query.

Comment: And that what ever your using to connect matches up with $db_connection variable.

Comment: You get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" if $db_connection does not match up to the variable used to connect to your database.

Comment: I have the db_connection problem solved, but the script you suggested isn't displaying the values of the field names. Whether I use `echo "first_name";` or what you suggested `echo first_name;` (without quotation marks). I don't get any errors. I just don't see any values displayed on the page.

Comment: You need to enter echo $first_name; as it is a variable, not a constant or a string. I did not suggest otherwise. 

Make sure you have actual data in your database and that the correct database is selected.

Comment: @ Frank_Hemsworth, I actually meant to include the `$` in front of the variable names in my last response, which I did in my attempt to use your solution. I still can't get the variable names (which are exactly as they appear in the table) to come up. I did, however, find a solution to the problem and posted it as an answer. Not sure why your code won't work on my machine, when it does for you :-/ Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Hello it is not recommended to use the mysql_ functions you should use the mysqli_ functions. Also it's a good idea to use prepared statements  like in my answer. 

Also your answer can be exploited using SQL injection so you SHOULD NOT USE THIS ON A PUBLIC WEBSITE. It is a security flaw that is why i suggested using prepared statements.

Comment: Maybe you are using a very old php version that does not support mysqli_ function and prepared statements. If so i would upgrade asap!

Comment: @ Frank_Hemsworth you are correct. The code is PHP 3. But I am not a PHP programmer. I'm trying to get by with an old membership software program until I can afford to have someone rewrite the whole system. Until then, I have to work with what I have. If you know code to accomplish my needs above, which I can use with the archaic PHP 3, it would be appreciated :)

Comment: If i were you i wouldn't even bother attempting to code with PHP3 as it's so old your site will get hacked in seconds. None (well most) of the things suggested here will not work with php3.

Comment: PHP3 is still PHP so upgrading to PHP5 wouldn't be too difficult as most of the PHP3 code will still be supported in PHP5. You can just solve the small errors that arise.

Comment: @ Frank_Hemsworth, the server has PHP5 installed. It is only the code that is PHP3. So as you explained, that should not be the problem I'm experiencing when attempting to use your suggested code. There is some other reason why I can't get it to work. I would gladly use your code if I could get it to work.